# How to search string contains a comma separated bad words in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to search if a user submitted comment contains comma separated bad words in the database.

Table `bad_word`:

| id | words |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo bar, fooBar |
| 2 | aaa bbb, ccc ddd |

I'm using the following code but it only work for one bad word per row on database:

```
$comment = request('comment');
$bad_word_exists = \App\BadWord::whereRaw("LOCATE(words, ?) > 0", [$comment])->exists();
```

**Expected output:**

| $comment | $bad_word_exists |
| --- | --- |
| foo | false |
| foo bar 123 | true |

Thanks

Comment: You need to normalise your data. Split all comma separated words into their own row in your `bad_word` table

Comment: @apokryfos That's what I did at first. But client wants to enter multi words at once separated by commas... Finally I handled it on php. Not sure if it can be handled directly on mysql.

Comment: @Wilson Then split them up and insert them as multiple rows.

Comment: @gre_gor But  I need to restore the data for user to update. i.e.: record 1: `foo bar, fooBar`. record 2: `aaa bbb, ccc ddd`

Comment: Then add a column so you can group them together again.

Comment: @miken32 No. That question requires an exact match of the string to a comma-separated string. But I require the string to be partially matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we convert the comma separated data into rows using `CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE()` then we search using `LOCATE()` function

```
with cte as (
  SELECT t.id, trim(j.words) as words
  FROM bad_word t 
  CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(words, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (words TEXT PATH '$')) j
)
select *
from cte
where LOCATE(words, 'foo bar 123') > 0 ;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/h0QKruqJ)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by apokryfos, it would be better to normalise the values in your `words` column.

If your client wants to add multiple words as a comma separated list, you can still enter them into your table as separate words:

```
$inbound_words = 'some, new, bad, words';
$new_bad_words = array_map(fn($word) => ['words' => trim($word)], explode(',', $inbound_words));

// assuming unique index on words column so using insertOrIgnore
DB::table('bad_word')->insertOrIgnore($new_bad_words);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need to restore the data for user to update. i.e.: record 1: `foo bar, fooBar`. record 2: `aaa bbb, ccc ddd`